# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bills'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting an error like 'Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bills'. Would there be solution to this?

````
enum Bills {
  BILL1 = 'BILL1',
  BILL2 = 'BILL2',
  BILL3 = 'BILL3',
}
const bill = 'BILL1'
const updatedBills = [Bills.BILL1, Bills.BILL2, Bills.BILL3];
const isBillUpdated = updatedBills.includes(bill)```
````

Comment: You can widen `updatedBills` from `Bills[]` to `readonly string[]` before calling `includes` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nl8rQN).  See the linked questions and answers for more information.